# Intervals in HiveQL

Tags: sql, database, hive, hiveql

I have a table consisting of two columns, the time and the value column. The time column is a float value, the value is a string value.

I would like to group all rows with the same value together where the distance between two values in the time column is maximal 0.001 and return intervals of these groups.

Example:
My table looks as follows:

```
====================
|  time   | value  |
====================
|  0.001  | a      |
|  0.00001| a      |
|  0.002  | a      |
|  0.002  | b      |
|  0.003  | b      |
|  0.0031 | a      |
====================
```

Desired Result:

```
======================================
|  time_min   |  time_max  |  value  |
======================================
|  0.001      |  0.002     | a      |
|  0.002      |  0.003     | b      |
|  0.0031     |  0.0031    | a      |
======================================
```

Is there an HiveQL query which does this (as efficiently as possible)?
Hive version: 1.2

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I thought it might be easier to ask this question about standard SQL but actually, I want to use it in HiveQL... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select      min(time)   as time_min
           ,max(time)   as time_max
           ,value       as value

from       (select      time
                       ,value

                       ,count(is_gap) over 
                        (   
                            partition by    value 
                            order by        time
                        )   as is_gap_seq

            from       (select      time
                                   ,value

                                   ,if 
                                    (
                                        time - lag(time) over 
                                            (partition by value order by time) > 0.001
                                       ,1
                                       ,null
                                    ) as is_gap

                        from        t
                        ) t
            ) t

group by    value
           ,is_gap_seq
;
```

P.s.

1. I'm using `IF` and not `CASE` because for some reason `CASE` yields the following error:

   FAILED: IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 2, Size: 2
2. using `FLOAT` for that purpose is a bad idea.
   It won't give you the results you are expecting for.